# Ruby Regex text parsing

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to parse a string that contains a bunch of values represented different ways. Here is what I have so far:

```
acc=acc.scan(/"([achievement|stat]).([\w]+.)*":[0-9]+/).flatten
```

which works for:

```
          {"stat.crouchOneCm":2392,"stat.craftItem.minecraft.bed":1,"stat.craftItem.minecraft.wooden_pickaxe":1
```

I get (exactly what I expect):

```
s
crouchOneCm
2392
s
bed
1
s
wooden_pickaxe
1
```

but doesnt work for something like this, in addition to the stuff above:

```
"achievement.exploreAllBiomes":{"value":0,"progress":["Desert","DesertHills","Ocean","Beach","Savanna Plateau M","Savanna","Savanna Plateau","River"]},"stat.craftItem.minecraft.iron_pickaxe":1,"
```

My goal was something like:

```
a
exploreAllBiomes
["Desert","DesertHills","Ocean","Beach","Savanna Plateau M","Savanna","Savanna Plateau","River"]
s
iron_pickaxe
1
```

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: That looks like JSON, so why not use a real parser?

Comment: ......because Im an idiot :)....derp

Comment: If not so, answer and close your question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh... the example string is not complete, but you're dealing with JSON...

```
require 'json'

hash = JSON['{"stat.crouchOneCm":2392,"stat.craftItem.minecraft.bed":1,"stat.craftItem.minecraft.wooden_pickaxe":1}']
hash
# => {"stat.crouchOneCm"=>2392,
#     "stat.craftItem.minecraft.bed"=>1,
#     "stat.craftItem.minecraft.wooden_pickaxe"=>1}
```